# Which algorithm does Matlab use in SVD?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, svd

I'm wondering if anyone knows which algorithm is used in matlab's standard svd() function?
'edit svd' does not reveal the code, and I have search through the mathworks question/answer and exchange.

I read somewhere that they use fortran for the svd, and that the code is here:
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/d2d/dgesvd_8f_source.html
But I didn't have much luck.

Anyone have experience with this? Or advice?

thanks!

Comment: They are most likely using LAPACK / SuiteSparse to compute the SVD.  Many of MATLAB's builtin functions that operate on matrices use it.  As for the specifics, I'm quite sure they're not just using the function out of the box - they're doing stuff before and after the call and that information is private and never released.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the *Diagnostics* section of the [help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html?refresh=true) mentions "QR steps".  It looks like they're using [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

Comment: thanks i never noticed that! and that makes sense with the other comment and what I just found on wikipedia "The second step can be done by a variant of the QR algorithm for the computation of eigenvalues, which was first described by Golub & Kahan (1965). The LAPACK subroutine DBDSQR implements this iterative method, with some modifications to cover the case where the singular values are very small (Demmel & Kahan 1990). Together with a first step using Householder reflections and, QR decomposition, this forms the DGESVD routine for the computation of the singular value decomposition."